# Como atribuir um Produto "Código" ao Pedido do Usuário

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Então galera eu estou modelando um banco em Mysql que possui 4 tabelas

- USUARIOS
- PEDIDOS
- PRODUTOS
- ESTOQUE

Um `PEDIDO` que possui `ID_USUARIO`, `ID_PRODUTO` e `STATUS`, e quando o pedido for realizado ele terá o `ESTADO = "PENDENTE"`, o que quero é quando eu aprovar no banco o pedido para "APROVADO" ele pegue um código `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` do meu estoque de mesmo `ID_PRODUTO` e atribua aquele pedido, onde o código só possa ser usado apenas uma vez e quando tiver outro pedido `"APROVADO"` ele atribua outro Código a outro pedido, parece simples, mas estou quebrando a cabeça com isso

Comment: E qual a regra de formação deste código que, pelo que entendi, varia a cada uso?

Comment: Não dá pra resolver via Trigger?